# Pop gesture stopped working when topBar is hidden

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

Swiping on the edge of the screen to pop was working for weeks until suddenly it stopped working after a rebuild of my app. Possibly in between updating package.

Whenever I set the topBar to visible: false, the pop gesture (swipe on the edge of the screen) won't trigger a pop anymore.

```
topBar: {
  drawBehind: false,
  visible: true,
  animate: false,
}
```

I'm using **2.1.3-patch.2** for react-native-navigation.

For react-native I'm using **0.57.7**

I would love to know if I'm maybe missing a something?